# Mongo DB Collection Scan OR Index Scan

Tags: mongodb, match, aggregation

I have an index on "timeofcollection". There is an issue that one query using same field shown collection is being scanned while on shown index scan. These are the "$match" steps in an aggregation pipeline I am posting below. Can someone help me out explaining what is an issue and how should I handle it?

If I have following in $match step in pipeline, it evaluates as an index scan

```
{
   "timeofcollection":{$gte:ISODate("2020-09-24T00:00:00.000+0000"),$lt:ISODate('2020-09-25T00:00:00.000+0000')}
}
```

If I have following step in pipeline, it evaluates as collection scan

{

```
        $match: {
                "$expr": {
                    "$and": [{
                            "$gte": [
                                "$_id.dt",
                                {
                                    "$subtract": [{
                                            "$toDate": {
                                                "$dateToString": {
                                                    "date": "$$NOW",
                                                    "format": "%Y-%m-%dT00:00:00.000+0000"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        },
                                        86400000
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                        },
                        {
                            "$lt": [
                                "$_id.dt",
                                {
                                    "$toDate": {
                                        "$dateToString": {
                                            "date": "$$NOW",
                                            "format": "%Y-%m-%dT00:00:00.000+0000"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
```

Basically what I am trying to achieve is to pull records falling in last day. This works fine but involves collection scan which I can not do.

Any help?

Comment: What percentage of the documents in your collection do you expect would fall in between this date range?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Around 6% to 7%.  Nearly 7 to 8 Lac records are there per day.

Comment: You should run `explainStats` on your query to see how Mongo is planning it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen explainStats is showing collection scan for above query.

Answer (score 1):

The query planner will only use an index for equality comparison when using the [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/index.html#expr) operator.

It will also only use the index when the values of the expressions are constant for the query.  Since the `$$NOW` variable is not bound until query execution begins, and will have a different value for every execution, the query planner will not use an index for a query using that variable.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a complete answer, but one obvious problem I see with your above aggregation is that, for some reason, you seem to be converting dates to text, only to convert them back to dates again.  Typically, if your filter were to contain a *function* of `timeofcollection`, then the index on `timeofcollection` might not be usable.  Try this version:

```
$match: {
            "$expr": {
                "$and": [
                    {
                        "$gte": [
                            "$_id.dt",
                            {
                                "$subtract": [ "$$NOW", 86400000 ]
                            }
                        ],
                    },
                    {
                        "$lt": [
                            "$_id.dt", "$$NOW",
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
```

Note that I am assuming here that `dt` in the above fragment is an alias for `timeofcollection`, defined somewhere earlier.

The key point here is that using `timeofcollection` inside a function might render your index unusable.  The above version may get around this problem.

Comment: I tried your json but still a collection scan. May be your json also has timeofcollection in expr causing it to be a collection scan.